# Cordova-plugin-dialogs - navigator.notification.alert() method isn't working on a real iOS device

Tags: ios, cordova-plugins

I'm experiencing very strange behavior of `navigator.notification.alert()` method.

On Android everything works fine and `navigator.notification.alert()` shows an alert window on demand as expected, but on iOS alert is shown as expected only 2-3 times (or never shown). After that alert window simply isn't shown, nor callback method passed into `navigator.notification.alert()` is invoked.

```
function errorCallback(xhr) {
    var message = "Unknown Error \n.";
    var statusErrorMap = {
        '400': "Invalid content. Please, try again.",
        '401': "Unauthorized access.",
        '403': "Forbidden resource can't be accessed.",
        '409': "Oops! Try to SEARCH THE WEB once again.",
        '500': "Something wrong with service. Try to SEARCH THE WEB once again.",
        '503': "Service unavailable. Please, try again in a minute."
    };
    if (xhr.status) {
        message = statusErrorMap[xhr.status];
    }
    if (xhr.readyState === 0) {
        message = "Please, check your network and try again later.";
    }
    navigator.notification.alert(message, null, "Network");
};
```

My assumption is that when `navigator.notification.alert()` gets invoked it successfully passes call to iOS implementation of plugin, but plugin itself doesn't send the response back to UI.

My configuration is as follows: iOS 8.4.1, cordova-ios: 3.9.2, cordova-plugin-dialogs: 1.2.1 dev.

Comment: Can you post your relevant code snippets?

Comment: Please, see my updated question =)

Comment: Guys, why downvoting? Is it something wrong with a question ?

Comment: I'm Sorry @Stanislav legorov. Unable to figure out anything from this.

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick, is there a way I can provide more details on that ?

Comment: My understanding is that, whenever you call the method navigator.notification.alert() with designated parameters passed (which you are doing), it should display the native iOS alert. Are you trying to tell that, it's not displaying the alert each time navigator.notification.alert() gets called??

Comment: Is the errorCallback(xhr) function is getting called each time?

Comment: If the errorCallback(xhr) is getting called and still the alert isn't displayed, then there is some issue.

Comment: Yes, it is =) The feeling is that plugin itself doesn't pass invocation result back to UI. My assumption is grounded on the fact the if we put callback method instead of null into navigator.notification.alert(), the callback isn't fired.

Comment: Hi, I encountered the same issue, do you have a solution?

Comment: @Leon, we've now temporarily switched to Android version instead.